# How to find word with underscore in pdf file?

Tags: pdf

I need to find word "evolve_model" in pdf file. Ho to do this? It seems that viewer does not understand underscores (_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preview.app, the default OS X PDF viewer, sees underscores and allows you to search them fine.

You can search for words or phrases with underscores by using the underscore in the search box, as below:

[image]